# So, what is the "greatest fears" and "most beloved" sections?

Tags: discussion, moderator-tools, fun

In [this answer](/a/252991/238126), Shog9 posted a screenshot that had two curious rows in it.

[image: Normal moderator tool rows with current physical location, greatest fears and most beloved]

Now, in the screenshot, they are empty. But what does get put there?

Comment: @Kevin Yeah. I should learn what words mean before I try to randomly insert them where they don't belong.

Comment: Pretty sure it's this thing called a "joke."

Comment: Funny how there's no question about the 'current physical location' item there.  How powerful do we think SE is?!

Comment: Just goes to show how much folks take a certain lack of privacy for granted now, @Keen. And no, I don't know your physical location. Right now...

Comment: @Keen I actually kind of guessed it was some sort of GeoIP type of thing, to be honest. I knew (or at least I thought) that you would see IPs.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The *real* moderator UI has other fields there.

Or maybe it doesn't; I have a user script I use to put stuff there, so it might just cut off after "seen". I forget.

Anyway, I wasn't about to leave that portion of the real UI visible in the screenshot. Even though I was testing this on a sockpuppet, it's just a bad habit to get into - make a mistake like that with a real account & suddenly you've leaked someone's personal information onto the 'Net. That's pretty rude.

So when I post screenshots like this, I usually replace the bits that shouldn't be posted with something ridiculous. I *could* just blur them out, but I like to hope this helps catch folks' attention a bit more effectively, and perhaps also serves as a reminder to moderators that they're acting as stewards and should handle other people's profiles with care even when it doesn't seem particularly necessary.

Comment: "That's pretty rude." Not only that, but also [in violation of the moderator agreement](http://meta.stackexchange.com/legal/moderator-agreement) (and probably several other contracts in the case of SE employees as well).

Comment: [my favorite mock is one used for new dupe UI](http://i.stack.imgur.com/4ANbL.png) "MY TITLE IS IN ALL CAPS..."